# If app is rejeced in TestFlight beta review, does that affect the app store review of the same build?

Tags: ios, testflight, beta

Follow-up question to: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234056/will-submitting-a-build-for-testflight-beta-testing-stop-the-final-review-test-f)

I submitted version 3.4 of my app for app store review.  Then I enabled beta testing for that same build.  Apple has (imo incorrectly) rejected that beta review build, while my app store submission still says "Waiting for Review".

My question is: does the beta rejection in any way affect the app store submission?  In other words, can I ignore the beta rejection and plunge ahead with the app store build?  (I don't want to wait 2 weeks only to find out that their web-site does not correctly handle this case.)

Answer (score 1):

Apple's review process applies to all beta builds sent through their TestFlight service on iTunes Connect. Your build has failed this review process.

The AppStore process is identical. Your build will also fail there (if they even let you submit for review).

Comment: My app is already submitted for review.  I'm wondering why my app store submission still says "Waiting for Review".  Also, the review process is only identical in theory, the feature they rejected has been in the app unchanged for 8 months (at least 6 app store reviews).

Comment: The review process doesn't always catch every issue -- you have to remember that your app is reviewed by humans. When they do catch an issue, there is a higher probability of them continuing to catch that same issue in future builds because it will have already been in their notes. You can include build notes if you feel that the rejection was erroneous.

Comment: Review process consistency aside, I still need to know if their web site is lying to me or not.  The beta was rejected, but the app store submission (which predates the beta) still says "Waiting for Review".  Why would the beta rejection not automatically reject the app store submission?

Comment: Perhaps they are not using the exact same build.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I've filed an appeal, hopefully will get to talk to one of those humans, and clear this up.  I'll update this thread when I know.

Answer (score 0):

Only a single data-point, but I have had exactly the same binary fail the Testflight Beta review and pass the full app store review. Both were in review in parallel (I had a good release candidate but wanted to use the Beta process to get a version out quicker for some additional translation testing).

In this specific example, the app was slow(ish) to start (it downloads a lot of data for offline use) and I think the Testflight Beta reviewer was just less patient!