# Will my TestFlight pre-release builds be deactivated if I submit the app for review?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

We're currently using TestFlight for testing an app and would like to submit the app for review to list on the store. Will this disable our TestFlight builds?

I've checked the [developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH38-SW3) and it isn't clear. It does say that pre-release builds will be removed once the app is *Ready for Sale*, but it doesn't say anything about how they'll be affected (if at all) simply by submitting for review.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234056/will-submitting-a-build-for-testflight-beta-testing-stop-the-final-review-test-f) asked here relates to how enabling TestFlight affects a review submission, the answer being that it doesn't, but it isn't clear whether this is true of the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this with one of my application. The TestFlight applications are available for usage when the application is in Review process.

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in the developer site that:

> When the app becomes Ready for Sale in the App Store, testing automatically stops on earlier builds, and you will be unable to view or test them.

Comment: So the implication being that *while being reviewed* testing is still active?

Comment: I am not sure but they have also mentioned `Before your app becomes Ready for Sale, the Prerelease pane lists all builds for all prerelease versions you have uploaded. After the app becomes Ready for Sale, some of the builds will be removed from the pane`

Comment: check here ... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH38-SW3

Comment: Yeah, I referenced that part in my question. It tells you how a Ready for Sale app affects TestFlight but not (explicitly) ones in review.